# How can I change Error messages in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, error-handling, scipy

This is the code:

```
    A = np.array([ [x1**2, x1, z1], [x2**2, x2, z2], [x3**2, x3, z3] ])
    B = np.array([y1, y2, y3])
    B = B.T

    global X
    try:
        X = linalg.solve(A, B)
    except TracebackError:
        raise InputValueError('Input values nopt compatible') from None
```

So basically I want to have this euqation solved (by scipy). If I have two of the same input tho, I get a Traceback Error. to make it more clear and clean, if the Traceback error accures, I want to have it changed to "InputValueError('Input values not compatible')". How exactly does this try/except work and how do I use it correctly?

p.s.: The code after "try" is obviously wrong and that's the part where I need your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for the `from None` part

```
try:
     X = linalg.solve(A, B)
except np.linalg.LinAlgError as e:
     print("Got: ", e)

     raise InputValueError('Input values nopt compatible')
```

Comment: It then says "'TracebackError' is not defined"

Comment: @Janis Wasn't it the error you got? If not, attach your error and change `except TracebackError as e:` to `except <error you get> as e:`

Comment: That's the weird part, i ger a Traceback error, but it does not work...

Comment: Please attach the full error output to the question

Comment: Without your solution:
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Klipp\Desktop\IFR_PCS\IFR_PCS", line 32, in <module>
    find_equation(-1,0,1, -1,0,1, 10,0,1)
  File "C:\Users\Klipp\Desktop\IFR_PCS\IFR_PCS", line 23, in find_equation
    X = linalg.solve(A, B)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\basic.py", line 214, in solve
    _solve_check(n, info)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\basic.py", line 29, in _solve_check
    raise LinAlgError('Matrix is singular.')
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Matrix is singular.```

Comment: `numpy.linalg.LinAlgError:` is the error so I am editing the answer to match

Comment: Still doesn't work, it does spit out the new error message, but the old one still there

Comment: Because I left a `print("Got ", e)` just for your reference. You can remove that print (from the except) and get what you expected

Comment: i removed it, still get:
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Klipp\Desktop\IFR_PCS\IFR_PCS", line 23, in find_equation
    X = linalg.solve(A, B)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\basic.py", line 214, in solve
    _solve_check(n, info)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\basic.py", line 29, in _solve_check
    raise LinAlgError('Matrix is singular.')
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Matrix is singular.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:```

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Klipp\Desktop\IFR_PCS\IFR_PCS", line 31, in <module>
    find_equation(-1,0,1, -1,0,1, 10,0,1)
  File "C:\Users\Klipp\Desktop\IFR_PCS\IFR_PCS", line 24, in find_equation
    except numpy.linalg.LinAlgError as e:
NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined
[Finished in 0.301s]```

Comment: I edited it to `except np.linalg.LinAlgError as e`, because you did `import numpy as np`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231851/discussion-between-tamir-and-janis).